# One talk/paper, two speakers/authors

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for an English word which would replace "a seminar/conference talk where each co-author of the paper gives approximately one half of the talk" which may or may not exist.

Comment: Are they interacting during the presentation? If so, perhaps a *dialog* (or *dialogue*)?

Comment: The talk is a talk, no matter how many people deliver it. You could say it was co-authored or co-delivered I guess, but it's still just a talk.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "talk" part since I know those events as presentations so maybe *co-presenters* would work?

Comment: There is **no such word**, because the rare need for it can be handled by a short phrase such as "the co-authors shared the presentation of the talk"

Comment: What about good old "joint presentation"?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned below, one wouldn't really need a word for this phenomenon - the phrase "shared conference presentation," or the longer "conference talk in which both my co-author and I presented" would work.

Any more specific term for what you are doing would necessarily have to come from the form of your presentation: dialogue if it's a conversation, debate if it's a confrontation (which, given that you are co-authors of a paper, I should hope this is not the case).